# Swapping rows along with key in Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am looking for a way to reordering a hashmap...Similar like Swapping two rows of hashmap with their respective key...

My hashmap is like, before swapping

```
["key1","value1"];
["key2","value2"];
["key3","value3"];
["key4","value4"];
```

After swapping key 1 and key 2,

```
["key4","value4"];
["key2","value2"];
["key3","value3"];
["key1","value1"];
```

I want to swap two rows along with the key.Is it possible in java?

Comment: I think you may need to use LinkedHashMap for this, removing and adding the elements at particular index.

Comment: Swapping values or ordering?

Comment: @Shark Order to be swapped.

Comment: Any particular reason why ordering matters in your hashmap?

Comment: My hashmap contains mediaDetails(fileSize,fileName,fileType) with their respective keys.Key is the file Id.In my case, i want to swap two values with their keys.

Comment: Could you update the question to highlight that your HashMap is a `HashMap<String, SomeClass>` instead of `<String, String>` ?

Comment: Swapping `HashMap` indexes makes no sense. You are either using the data structure wrong or you are using the wrong data structure.

Comment: ok @Sedrick.Is it possible to rotate the hashmap from one point of position to other point of position?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with hash map.
`HashMap` doesn't guarantee the ordering. For that you make look into [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Swapping with `LinkedHashMap`

```
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> oldMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    oldMap.put("key1", "value1");
    oldMap.put("key2", "value2");
    oldMap.put("key3", "value3");
    oldMap.put("key4", "value4");
    System.out.println(oldMap);

    ArrayList<String> keySetList = new ArrayList<>();
    keySetList.addAll(oldMap.keySet());

    Collections.swap(keySetList, 0, 3);

    // our output map
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> swappedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for(String oldSwappedKey:keySetList) {
        swappedMap.put(oldSwappedKey, oldMap.get(oldSwappedKey));
    }

    System.out.println(swappedMap);
```

Swapping `1` and `4`

```
Input map:{key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3, key4=value4}
Output map:{key4=value4, key2=value2, key3=value3, key1=value1}
```

Comment: is it possible to change the index of two hashmaps and put it on new Hashmap then override with old hashmap? (kind of hack tips :P )

Comment: Can you swap it with keys in Linkedhashmap?with code snippet

Comment: Edited to include a sample swap with `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: suppose if I want to swap 1 and 3?how should I give positions as input?

Comment: Oh I thought you want to swap 1 with 2 only. But we can extend this logic to include any two swap points. We can insert the keys in a linked list, then swap the keys in a linked list, then create a new LinkedHashMap using the linkedList we created along with the Old LinkedHashMap. This would have some space overhead though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169592/discussion-between-shanu-gupta-and-ajay-jayendran).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? Parametrize the keys, but this should end up "swapping" values behind key1 and key2.

```
private void test(HashMap<MyKey, MyValue> map) {
    Set<MyKey> keyset = map.keySet();
    MyKey key1 = keyset.get(0);
    MyKey key2 = keyset.get(1);

    MyValue val1;
    MyValue val2;

    if (map.containsKey(key1)) {
        val1 = map.get(key1);
    }

    if (map.containsKey(key2)) {
        val2 = map.get(key2);
    }

    if (val2 != null)
    map.put(key1, val2);
    if (val1 != null)
    map.put(key2, val1);
}
```